# Scrolling parallax effects on objects

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to recreate the parallax effect that can be seen on Apple's iPhone 6s webpage: [click](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/)

The iPhone objects have a slight, floaty, parallax animation when you scroll up or down. I'd like to find an easy way to recreate this for multiple objects on my webpage. I've found ScrollMagic and Skrollr but they seem overly complex for what I am trying to accomplish.

So for example, how would I animate [these black boxes](https://jsfiddle.net/fbxy4thy/6/) to animate the same way as the iPhones?

Does anyone know of a quick way to implement this with HTML/CSS/JS?

Thanks for the help!

```
<div class="box1">

</div>

<div class="box2">

</div>

<div class="box3">

</div>

<div class="box4">

</div>


html{
  height: 1500px;
  width: 800px;
}

.box1{
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  top: 260px;
    left: 56%;
}

.box2{
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  top: 360px;
    left: 56%;
}
.box3{
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  top: 260px;
    left: 16%;
}
.box4{
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  top: 320px;
    left: 86%;
}
```

Comment: skrollr (the only one of those two I have experience with) isn't that complex really if you ask me. See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/b9dxzwaj/ It works pretty close (not exact, but still nice.) The trick is getting the same elasticity from the parallaxed objects. With some tweaking maybe...

Answer (score 0):

My comment was moderated so I will try once more.

The following code might help you.

```
$( window ).scroll(e=>{
    // get scroll direction
    let direction = 'down';
    if ( this.oldScroll > this.scrollY ) direction = 'up';
    this.oldScroll = this.scrollY;

    animate('.box1', direction);
    animate('.box2', direction, 3);
});

function animate( element, direction, speed, smooth ){
    element = $( element )
    speed = speed || 2;
    smooth = smooth || 2;

    // get element offset
    let Y = parseInt( element.attr('data-y') || 0 );

    // Calculate movement
    if ( direction == 'down' ) Y = Y - (1*speed)
    else Y = Y + (1*speed)

    // Apply values
    element.css({
        'transition': smooth + 's transform',
        'transform' : 'translateY(' + Y.toFixed(2) + 'px)',
    })
    // store new element offset
    element.attr('data-y', Y)
}
```

You execute the function for each element on windows scroll. You can pass values for the speed and smoothness of the movement.

The function calculates the movement and applies `transform: translateY()` and `transition: 2s transform;` attributes to the element.

I have a more complete version of the code on [code.actus.works/act-parallax](https://code.actus.works/act-parallax/)